# What are pythonic methods for implementing random roll tables?

Tags: python, random

A random roll table is a table used for random generation in tabletop games and the like. While they can be very simple they can also trend towards the complex.

An unusual example of a random roll table would be Wheel of Fortune-style games where certain categories can have a higher chance of occurring.

I'm building a random generator for D&D 5e magic items (see here: https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/bg0h46/5e_magic_item_generator/) but I've decided I want to weight the tables to prefer certain results certain times.

A very simple table may look like this:

```
(1d6)
1: First result
2: Second result
3: Third result
4: Fourth result
5: Fifth result
6: Sixth result
```

This can be resolved pretty easily by using a list and randomising between 1 and 6.

A slightly more complex (but still 1d6-based) table may look like this:

```
(1d6)
1-3: First result
4-5: Second result
6: Third result
```

My tables are more likely to look like:

```
(1d20)
1-5: First result
6-15: Second result
16-17: Third result
18: Fourth result
19: Fifth result
20: Sixth result
```

These tables have higher `weighting` towards certain categories to allow for those categories to be selected more often. In my magic item example, swords should have 6-15 as a `metal` blade whereas 1-5 would be a `bone` blade and 20 would be something very unusual like a `darkness` blade or a `light` blade.

One possible option is to add a `weight` to each category and perform a calculation on each roll to see what weight it lands on by adding together the previous weights but this feels horribly clunky.

I tried to implement this item generator previously in PHP and I used a switch case with comparison operators on the cases to solve this but, obviously, this does not work in Python.

What would be the recommend Python design for this weighted table implementation or does anyone have any ideas for implementation whatsoever? I'm willing to rewrite my data structure completely to take advantage of any ideas.

Comment: Any reason to not use a simple 20 element list? Then you just pick a random number between 1 and 20. Or do you just want a function that picks a random item with weighted probability?

Comment: @Dan mostly due to having a lot of these tables and I require weighted probability for certain things as I mention above. There's also data duplication issues which, if I need to change anything, will result in me needing to change a lot of dictionary elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Use a `list` with one element per number on your die - This has the advantage of the algorithm mapping very closely to the act of rolling the dice and looking up the result from a table. The disadvantage is it would scale badly for say a 10 000 sided dice. But that's probably not a concern for you.

```
roll_results = ([first_result] * 5 
                + [second_result] * 10 
                + [third_result] * 2
                + [fourth_result,
                   fifth_result,
                   sixth_result])

roll = random.randint(0, 20)
result = roll_results[roll]
```

Option 2: Use a [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) - this is an efficient mathematical approach. It will scale well. But it's more complicated to understand if you don't know statistics and doesn't map as obviously to the use case.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

import numpy as np

options = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
weights = np.array([5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1])
pdf = weight/np.sum(weights)
cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)

def get_item(cdf, options):
    roll = np.random.random()
    idx = bisect_left(cdf, roll)  # This uses a binary search to find the point on the CDF (F) such that F(roll) == P(X <= roll)
    return options[idx]
```

Option 3: Do exactly what you did in PhP:

```
options = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
roll = random.randint(1, 21)
if 1 <= roll <= 5:
    return option[0]
elif 6 <= roll <= 15
    return option[1]
elif 16 <= roll <= 17
    return option[2]
elif roll == 18
    return option[3]
elif roll == 19
    return option[4]
elif roll == 20
    return option[5]
```

---

If you have many of these tables, I would suggest using option two but wrapping it up in a class or a closure:

```
class OptionsWeightsLengthMismatchException(BaseException):
    """Raises when the number of elements in the options list doesn't match the number of elements in the weight list."""
    pass


# Using an class (OOP approach):
class RollTable:

    def __init__(self, options: List[Any], weights: np.array) -> "RollTable":
        self.options = options
        self.weights = weights
        self._validate_inputs()
        pdf = weights/np.sum(weights)
        self.cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)

    def _validate_inputs(self) -> None:
        if len(self.options) != self.weights.size:
            raise OptionsWeightsLengthMismatchException(f"options and weights must have the same number of elements.")
        if max(self.weights.shape) != np.prod(self.weights.shape): # i.e. make sure it's 1D
            raise ValueError("Weights must be 1D, i.e. only one non-singular dimension.")

    def get_item(self):
        roll = np.random.random()
        idx = bisect_left(self.cdf, roll)
        return self.options[idx]


#Use it like:
table_1 = RollTable(["a", "b"], np.array([3, 2]))

for _ in range(10):
    print(table_1.get_item())

# =============================================================================
# using a closure (functional programming approach)
def make_roll_table(options: List[Any], weights: np.array) -> Callable[[None], Any]:
    # Do the input validation here
    pdf = weights/np.sum(weights)
    cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)

    def get_item():
        roll = np.random.random()
        idx = bisect_left(cdf, roll)
        return options[idx]

    return get_item


# Use it like
get_item_from_table_2 = make_roll_table(["a", "b", "c"], np.array([3, 1, 1]))

for _ in range(10):
    print(get_item_from_table_2())
```

Comment: I think Option 1 may work and Option 2 is a very good idea. Option 3 doesn't really work simply due to the amount of these tables I've built (and will continue to build).

Comment: Agreed - option 3 also has more room for error and is messy to maintain. If you have to do this for many lists, I would suggest using option 2 and wrapping up the cdf calculation with it using a class or a closure. I'll add examples.

Comment: @MeridarchGekkota Added some more complete solutions to make option 2 reusable for making many roll tables

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to simply use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). Your second example would simply be:

```
>>> random.choice([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
```

Your third is simply:

```
>>> choices = [1]*5 + [2]*10 + [3]*2 + [4, 5, 6]
>>> random.choice(choices)
```

Comment: I think the random.choice option may work with a weighting element in the dictionaries and it solves duplication issues. I hadn't been aware of random.choice up to now so this is exceptionally useful for me.